# Microsoft Dynamics CRM EasyRePro automated test Selenium Error - ElementClickInterceptedException

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, easyrepro

I am trying to set up some automated tests for a Microsoft Dynamics CRM inhouse application.  For this, I am using C# (Visual Studio 2017), Selenium (Version 3.14), as well as EasyRePro, and ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6.

The problem that I am having is when I try to do a second Browser.Grid.Switchview within my code I get the following error "Exception Experienced: OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (211, 38). Other element would receive the click:"

I have tried a number of different ways to not get the "Exception Experienced: OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (211, 38). Other element would receive the click:".  These include adding;

```
_browser.Grid.Refresh();
_browser.Grid.ClearSearch();
```

between the two "_browser.Grid.SwitchView"

I have also tried to first reopen the subarea by navigating to the subarea again like this

```
   _browser.Navigation.OpenSubArea("RibbonValue", "SubAreaValue");
```

between the two "_browser.Grid.SwitchView"

Then I tried first going to AnotherSubAreaValue and then going back to the SubAreaValue.

```
   _browser.Navigation.OpenSubArea("RibbonValue", "AnotherSubAreaValue");
   _browser.Navigation.OpenSubArea("RibbonValue", "SubAreaValue");
```

between the two "_browser.Grid.SwitchView"

My code is as follows;

```
MyExtentReport _myReport;
Browser _browser;
IWebDriver _driver;

try{
    //Test start
    //LogInfo --> start building an HTML report page
    _browser.Navigation.OpenSubArea("RibbonValue", "SubAreaValue");
    _myReport.LogInfo("NAVIGATE:   RibbonValue > SubAreaValue");
    _browser.ThinkTime(200);

    try{
        // Switch the screen to the first grid view
        // LogPass --> this will record the test as a pass and take a screenshot and output to the HTML report page we are building.
        _browser.Grid.SwitchView("First Grid View");
        _browser.ThinkTime(2000);
        _myReport.LogPass(testCaseName + "This test Passed " + "\"" + "First Grid View" + "\" view is available");
        _browser.ThinkTime(2000);
    } catch (InvalidOperationException ex){
        _myReport.LogFail(testCaseName + "This test Failed " + "\"" + "First Grid View" + "\" view is NOT available");
        _browser.ThinkTime(2000);
    }

    try{
        // Switch the screen to the first grid view
        // LogPass --> this will record the test as a pass and take a screenshot and output to the HTML report page we are building.
        _browser.Grid.SwitchView("Second Grid View");
        _browser.ThinkTime(2000);
        _myReport.LogPass(testCaseName + "This test Passed " + "\"" + "Second Grid View" + "\" view is available");
        _browser.ThinkTime(2000);
    } catch (InvalidOperationException ex){
        _myReport.LogFail(testCaseName + "This test Failed " + "\"" + "Second Grid View" + "\" view is NOT available");
        _browser.ThinkTime(200);
    }

 } catch (Exception e){
     _myReport.LogError("Exception Experienced:  " + e);
 }
```

I would expect that the _browser.Grid.SwitchView should switch between the various views that are being requested on a particular Microsoft Dynamics CRM Sub Area.

Comment: this means that there is an element on-top (overlayed) of the element you are trying to click.  Post the markup.

Comment: Alternatively you can try with js click, FYI.